# Mongoose returns Mongo object, but can't access property on it

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose

In my simple Node/Mongo/Mongoose setup, I have a function that calls the server to see what the highest ID I'm using currently is, and return the next ID. This function takes as a callback the functionality that creates a new `Game`.

Weird: The `logger.log` as it appears below outputs

```
result { _id: 555d83d5bb0d4e3c352d896f, gameId: 'NaN' }
```

but when I change the logger to

```
logger.log("result", result.gameId);
```

the output is

```
result { _id: 555d83d5bb0d4e3c352d896f, gameId: 'NaN' }
```

which makes no sense. Clearly that property is there!

Here is my code

```
var createGame = function(gameNickname, callback){
    nextGameId(function(nextId){

        var newgame = new models.Game({
            "gameId": Number(nextId),
            "gameNickname": gameNickname
        });
        newgame.save(function(result, game){
            callback(result + nextId);
        });
    });


};
var nextGameId = function(callback){
    var games = models.Game.find({}, {gameId: 1});
    games.sort('-gameId').limit(1) //get the highest number roundId and add 1 to it
    .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) logger.log(err);
        if (result === null){
            callback(0);
        }
        else{
            logger.log("result", result);
            callback(result.gameId);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend you use autoincrement mongoose plugin, somthing like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');

var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/db");

autoIncrement.initialize(connection);

var GameSchema = {
    "gameId":       {type: Number},
    "gameNickname": {type: String}
}

GameSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, { model: 'Game', field: 'gameId' });

mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema);
```

after this you can save your game with autoinc, for example:

var Game = mongoose.model('Game');

```
function createNewGame(nickname){
    return new Game({gameNickname: nickname}).save(function(err, res){
      console.log(res);
      //some code...
   })
}
```

after execute this code you should have somnthing like this:

```
{
    _id:          "555d83d5bb0d4e3c352d896f",
    gameNickname: "nickname",
    gameId:        1
}
```

Comment: This is awesome I hadn't heard about this. It works great. Thanks!